# rspec association creation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec2

I have a model `item has_many ratings` and a `ratings belongs_to item`  `ratings belongs_to user` I want to force a user who is creating an item to rate it too. Other users can then rate it later on. item and user have no association in my model. 
I am doing the following in my item_spec which is giving me an error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` on line `@item =  Item.new(name: "Item1",` below.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :item
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :name , :length => { minimum: 3 }
  validates :category , :length => { minimum: 3 }
  validates_presence_of :ratings
end

require 'spec_helper'

describe Item do
  before do
    @item =  Item.new(name: "Item1",
                      url: "www.item1.com",
                      full_address: "Item1Address",
                      city: "Item1City",
                      country: "Item1Country",
                      category: "Item1Type",
                      ratings_attributes:  {"rating" => "3", "comment" =>  "Ahh Good"} )
  end
```

Also using FactoryGirl I am doing something like this

```
factory :item do
    before_create do |r|
      r.ratings<< FactoryGirl.build(:ratings, item: r )
    end
    name "Item1"
    url "www.Item1.com"
    full_address "Item1Address"
    city "Item1City"
    country "Item1Country"
    category "Item1Category"
  end  

  factory :ratings do
    rating      3
    comment     "Its not that bad"
    user
  end
end
```

which again is not yeilding the desired result. 

can anyone help me solve this problem please.Thanks!

Comment: Would you share your stacktrace or confirm that the line from your spec is at the top of the trace?  Also, would you share the `initialize` definition from your `Item` model if there is one?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin added the information requested  stacktrace for error `2) Item 
     Failure/Error: @item =  Item.new(name: "Item1",
     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
     # ./spec/models/item_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: I assume in the code above that you've concatenated your `Item` model file with your spec file, because otherwise the line number #5 doesn't make sense.

Comment: One thing I'm confused about is that you have `has_many :ratings` which implies the existence of a `Rating` (singular) class, but you also have a `Ratings` (plural) class and a `ratings` attribute of `Item`. Would you share your `Rating` and `Ratings` models?

Comment: `class Ratings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item, inverse_of: :ratings
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates_presence_of :item
  validates_numericality_of :rating, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
  validates_numericality_of :rating, :less_than_or_equal_to => 5
end`

Comment: I dont have a Rating model. Also I am using Inflections for circumventing plural and singular mismatch. @PeterAlfvin Sorry for the late comment. and Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code, now having problem testing some association order, but at least the desired functionality working.

```
factory :item do
    name "Item1"
    url "www.Item1.com"
    full_address "Item1Address"
    city "Item1City"
    country "Item1Country"
    category "Item1Category"
  end

  factory :ratings, :class => 'Ratings' do
    association :item, factory: :item, strategy: :build
    user
    rating      3
    comment     "Its not that bad"
  end

  factory :item_with_rating, parent: :item do
    ratings {[FactoryGirl.create(:ratings)]}
  end
```

Here is the spec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Item do
  before do
    @item =  FactoryGirl.create(:item_with_rating)
  end

  subject { @item }
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:url) }
  it { should respond_to(:full_address)}
  it { should respond_to(:city) }
  it { should respond_to(:country) }
  it { should respond_to(:category) }
  it { should respond_to(:ratings) }
  it { should_not respond_to(:type) }
  it { should_not respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should be_valid }
```

There is no change in the Model file for item